# ASP.NET and Remoting

Tags: asp.net, remoting

I have a .net application running on server. Now I want to comunicate between my ASp.NET website and the server application.
Currently I use database, server writes info to the db and site uses it etc. However adding new fields to echange and exchanging complex object is a pain.
Is remoting the way out? If yes, what are the common things to keep in mind while doing this.

1. both server and asp.net site is on the same server
2. both is under my control
3. is there any other better way than using remoting?
4. It is .NET 2.0

Answer (score 0):

The purists will say that remoting is an old, dead technology, and the way to do it now is to use [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you're attempting to have some SOA thing, the best thing is to a web service for your server application and access it from your ASP.net website application. It's the best way to do.

However I don't really understand what the purpose of the "server" is? Couldn't your ASP.net website - as you say - be your front-end of the server application?? Your "server" would then simply be the business and data layer and there would be no need to use remoting or WCF.

Comment: Server is actually a game server. Clients connect to the server using sockets and server can not be elemenated.

Answer (score 0):

I would say [webservices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972326.aspx)  if want to stay .net 2.0, otherwise it think you should take a look at [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you need direct interaction between assemblies (ASP.NET and some server application or service) you should use Application Domains and cross-domain calls (some good example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/CrossDomainRemoting.aspx)) or using WCF, which is better. Also you can use web services if your server application can be accessed via web without major resulting drawbacks (security issues, server deployment change, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, u can deploy a WebService on that server. WebService is base on SOAP, it can exchange data object with your website.

If you can update to .Net Framwwork 3.5, you can try to use WCF instead.